# Create custom column based off of other columns in SQL query (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a hard time finding correct syntax to do the following:

```
SELECT
ColumnA,
ColumnB,
ColumnC,
(if Column1 IS Null and Column2 IS NOT NULL) Then 'Pending' Else '' AS ColumnD
```

I've tried IF/ELSE, IIF(), but I can't seem to get these queries to work.

Answer (score 2):

use `case when expression`

```
SELECT ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,
case when Column1 IS Null and Column2 IS NOT NULL Then 'Pending' Else '' end AS ColumnD 
from yourtable
```